# Minimum number of steps to guess an item in a database given a liar

Tags: game-theory

Let's say I have a database of $N\times N$ size ($N$ rows and $N$ columns).
My friend wants me to guess the location of an item. We start by binary guess, meaning I ask him if it is in upper half and he says yes or no, if it's in the upper half, then I ask if it is in left upper half or right upper half, and he again answers me and so on.

What are the minimum number of guesses I have to make to guess the location correctly given that he is allowed to lie twice?

Comment: Could you share any attempts you have already made to solve this?